# How can I restrict access to a user who has full mailbox rights in Exchange 2010?

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010

I have a problem where Users[1..10] have Full Mailbox Access to UserA's mailbox.

UserA, now wants to restrict access so that all the Users[1..10] have access except to the "Sent Items" and "Deleted Items". In this User2 & User3 should carry on having access as previously requested.

Is there a simple way for me to restrict access to the folder without having to remove the Full Mailbox Right permission and apply each individual's user rights on each specific folder?

Sorry if this has been asked before and answered. I did look but I think Google could not understand my query.

I am doing this via powershell as this will need to be repeated numerous times across multiple mailboxes.

referenced from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848808/how-do-i-restrict-specific-folders-for-a-user-with-full-mailbox-rights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Sembee.

For those of you having to do this. Here is a quick and dirty script to do this. Please, test it before you use on a live mailbox and adapt as needed.

```
# The mailbox to apply the permissions changes on
$mailbox = "target@domain.com"

# The users to add to the mailbox folder list
$users = "user1@domain.com"

# Get a list of folders in the mailbox defined above. We want only the folder path
$folderlist = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $mailbox | select FolderPath

# Create a List item consisting of string objects
[Collections.Generic.List[String]]$sList = New-Object -TypeName Collections.Generic.List[String]

# Loop through the entire list of folders and do something
foreach ($folder in $folderlist)
{
# Get the folderpath object from the folderlist and output it as a string value
$sfoldername = $folder.FolderPath | Out-String

# Look for the tree node called "Top of Information Store" and replace it with a /
$sfname = $sfoldername -replace "/Top of Information Store","/"

# replace all back slashes with forward slashes
$sfname = $sfname  -replace "/","\"

# remove any hidden characters that might be lurking around in the string
$sfname = $sfname.Trim()

    #Perform a bunch of IF statements in a simple way.
    switch($sfname)
    {
        # System Folder in Mailbox. Do nothing if these are encountered
        "\Recoverable Items" {break;}
        "\Deletions" {break;}
        "\Purges" {break}
        "\Versions"{break;}
        "\Quick Step Settings"{break}
        "\Conversation Action Settings"{break;}
        "\News Feed"{break;}

        # Add the folder name into the list of strings defined earlier
        default{$sList.Add($sfname);break}
    }    
}

# For each item in the list of strings apply permissions

foreach ($item in $sList)
{
    # concatenate the foldername to contain the mailbox name and the folder path in a format the Set and Add permission command can understand.

    $foldername = $mailbox + ":" + $item | Out-String
    # remove any hidden characters that might be lurking around in the string
    $fname = $foldername.Trim()

    # Add the permissions on the folder assuming permissions haven't already been set
    Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $fname -AccessRights Owner -User $users

    # If the user permissions already exists then set / update the permissions
    Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $fname -AccessRights Owner -User $users
}
```

Ensure you are very careful with this. One thing to note, if you want to use a group for controlling access, ensure you set the group as a security group in active directory and then use as a Distribution Group. Otherwise, using a group for access control will not work.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Full access trumps everything else as highest permissions wins with Exchange, so full mailbox is higher than folder level permission.

Therefore the only option is to remove Full Mailbox Access and grant permissions at a folder level.

You should be able to PowerShell something that grants the permissions to all folders in the mailbox, then removes the permissions on the required folders. However that would also mean that new top level folders would need the permissions changing on them (new sub folders inherit).